# Match text(a..b) from the last occurrence of a word(a) till first occurrence of another word(b)

Tags: ruby, regex

Using regular expression on the following input:

**Input**

```
response {
   id: 1
   files: 1.bin
   major: 338013710701
   status: Received
}
response {
   id: 1
   files: 1.bin
   major: 35723057325
   status: Valid
}
response {
   id: 1
   files: 1.bin
   major: 27151510570
   status: Accepted
}
```

I am expecting the matched output:

**Expected Output**

```
response {
   id: 1
   files: 1.bin
   major: 27151510570
   status: Accepted
```

where `id: 1` is mandatory for a match. I tried to do it with the following regular expression:

```
/response {\n {3}id: 1.*?status: Accepted/m
```

and it selects from the first `response` till `status: Accepted`. Can anyone help in framing the right regular expression to match the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match the response block which contains the string `status: Accepted`,

```
/response\s*\{\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n\s*status: Accepted/m
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/FfLqezfvA6)

**Explanation:**

- `response` Matches a literal string response.
- `\s*` Zeror or more spaces.
- `{` A literal `{` symbol.
- `\n` Matches a newline character.
- `[^\n]*` Matches anycharacter not of newline zero or more times.
- `\n` Matches a newline character.
- `[^\n]*` Matches anycharacter not of newline zero or more times.
- `\n\s*` A newline and zero or more spaces.
- `status: Accepted` Matches the string `status: Accepted`

**Update:**

You could use this regex also,

```
/response {[\s\n\w\.:]*id:\s*1[\s\n\w\.:]*status: Accepted/m
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/8t9rFnoIP1)

Comment: Can you explain me what the above expression is doing?

Comment: I have modified the input slightly and tried the same. I have some issues in matching the block from Line 19 to Line 25. Can u have a look at it in the following link http://www.rubular.com/r/BYC4dD6tp8

Comment: did you want the answer for above comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56696/discussion-between-miz-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
/(.*(response.*?status: Accepted))/s
```

you will get it in the second backreference

`\2` or `$2`

demo here: http://regex101.com/r/aO2qD8/1